# No bean named 'transactionManager' available using multiple transaction manager

Tags: spring-data-jpa, datasource, transactionmanager

I am using spring JPA to connect to my master & slave databases.
I have created two transaction managers, one for master database & another one for slave & named them masterTransactionManager and slaveTransactionManager respectively.

But when I am trying to use my slaveTransactionManager using @Transactional annotation, it is still looking for default "transactionManager".

I have tried it with value & transactionManager parameter of the Transactional annotation.
Any idea why it can happen?

Below is my code :-

```
 @Override
      @Transactional(value = "slaveTransactionManager")
      public EmailDTO getDataByIdSlave(Long dataId, Long brandId) {
        emailDataSlaveRepository.findAll();
        return null;
      }
```

Below is one of my slave data config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = BeanConstant.SLAVE_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY,
    transactionManagerRef = DataConfigConstant.SLAVE_TRANS_MANAGER,
    basePackages = {DataConfigConstant.SLAVE_REPO_PACKAGE}
)
public class SlaveDataSourceConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(BeanConstant.JPA_REPO)
  private Map<String, Object> jpaRepo;

  @Bean(BeanConstant.SLAVE_DATA_SOURCE_PROPERTIES)
  @ConfigurationProperties(DataConfigConstant.SLAVE_DATA_SOURCE)
  public DataSourceProperties slaveDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Bean(name = BeanConstant.SLAVE_DATA_SOURCE)
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = DataConfigConstant.SLAVE_DATA_SOURCE)
  public DataSource slaveDataSource(@Qualifier(BeanConstant.SLAVE_DATA_SOURCE_PROPERTIES) DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = BeanConstant.SLAVE_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY)
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                     @Qualifier(BeanConstant.SLAVE_DATA_SOURCE) DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).properties(jpaRepo).packages(DataConfigConstant.ENTITY_PACKAGE).persistenceUnit
        (DataConfigConstant.SLAVE_REPO_PROCESS_NAME).build();
  }

  @Bean(name = DataConfigConstant.SLAVE_TRANS_MANAGER)
  @Qualifier(value = DataConfigConstant.SLAVE_TRANS_MANAGER)
  public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
      @Qualifier(BeanConstant.SLAVE_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY) EntityManagerFactory
          barEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
  }
```

Comment: I'm confused. You are talking about the masterTransactionManager  but the examples uses slaveTransactionManager?

Comment: Hi Simon,
Sorry for the confusion, I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by following :

I was using EnableJpaRepositories annotation on my main class apart from data source config classes hence there were total three transaction managers.

1) Transaction manager by EnableJpaRepositories from main/driver class.
2) MasterTransactionManager.
3) SlaveTransactionManager.

As soon as I removed EnableJpaRepositories from main class,it started working properly.